# reading firebird db, i/o error when rdbms opens db

Tags: firebird

I'm using Firebird as rdbms. When db is connected and open using flamerobin I cannot access to the same db from my winforms application, I'm getting i/o error.

Database is embedded firebird stored on my local disk c.

Error message is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll

Additional information: I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\DB\DEMOFB.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firebird version before 2.5 then thats the limit of the embedded engine - only single connection per database is allowed. Starting with 2.5 simultaneous access to the same database from different embedded server modules is allowed.